# Func as a property with types it doesn't know about

Tags: c#, class, generics

Is a way, in C#, to have a Func as a property of a class, but for it to refer to a type that it doesn't know (or care) about?

For example, let's say we're trying to define a filter:

Project A:

```
// Project A doesn't know about Person

public class MyListType {

   public MyListType(string listName) {
      ListName = listName;
   }

   public string ListName {get; set;}

   public Func<List<Person>, List<Person>> Filter {get; private set;}

   public ProjectA WithFilter(Func<List<Person>, List<Person>> filter) {
      Filter = filter;
      return this;
   }
}
```

Project B:

```
public class Person {

    public Person (string name) {
       Name = name;
    }

    public string Name {get; set;}

}

public class ClassB1 {

    var beginsWithA = new MyListType ("Begins with 'A'").WithFilter(new Func<List<Person>, List<Person>> ((persons) => {
       return persons.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A"));
    }

    var people = new List<Person> {
         new Person("Alan"), new Person ("Alison"), new Person ("Blinky"), 
         new Person("Beatrice"), new Person("Xavier"), new Person ("Zebedee") };

    var aPeople = beginsWithA.Filter(names);

}
```

So obviously Project A won't compile in this case, because it doesn't know about `Person`. But logically it doesn't need to, since project B is the only one that works with this class. `MyListType` just needs to know, "there's a filter that someone might be calling, but they'll handle how the filter works themselves so don't worry about it".

With that in mind, is there a way of assigning this filter as a property?

I've tried

```
Func<List<object>, List<object>>
```

but it won't convert between `Person` and `object`.

I've also been trying

```
WithFilter<T>(Func<List<T>, List<T>> filter)
```

but then I can't assign the filter to the property because it doesn't know what `T` is.

Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Why do you not make `MyListType` generic aswell? That way, you can just have a `Func<List<T>, List<T>> Filter { get; set; }`?

Comment: Unfortunately in my case MyListType is a much more complex class than the above illustration, which is accessed in many places throughout the solution. I would rather not disturb what's there too much for what is a relatively minor update if possible...

Comment: @komodosp: In that case you might want to consider using a different class, which is _composed_ of your current list class and your Filter functionality, rather than further complicating your existing class with details which evidently have nothing to do with most of the class's use cases.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to solve this problem is to make your list type generic:

```
public class MyListType<T> {

   public MyListType(string listName) {
      ListName = listName;
   }

   public string ListName {get; set;}

   public Func<List<T>, List<T>> Filter {get; private set;}

   public MyListType<T> WithFilter(Func<List<T>, List<T>> filter) {
      Filter = filter;
      return this;
   }
}
```

Your other code doesn't compile as-is, but it can be made to work with some changes:

```
var beginsWithA = new MyListType<Person>("Begins with 'A'")
    .WithFilter(new Func<List<Person>, List<Person>>((persons) =>
{
    return persons.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A")).ToList();
}));


var people = new List<Person> {
         new Person("Alan"), new Person ("Alison"), new Person ("Blinky"),
         new Person("Beatrice"), new Person("Xavier"), new Person ("Zebedee") };

var aPeople = beginsWithA.Filter(people);
```

I would probably eliminate the `WithFilter` function, though: it's more idiomatic to use the property, and then it's more clear that there's only one filter, and that setting it mutates your object rather than creating a new transformation.

You can make the `Filter` `required` to avoid null references at runtime.

```
public class MyListType<T>
{
   public MyListType(string listName) {
      ListName = listName;
   }

   public string ListName {get; set;}

   public required Func<List<T>, List<T>> Filter {get; init;}
}

// ...
var beginsWithA = new MyListType<Person>("Begins with 'A'")
{
    Filter = persons =>persons.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A")).ToList()
};
```

Or, using C# 12:

```
public class MyListType<T>(string ListName)
{
   public required Func<List<T>, List<T>> Filter {get; init;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your class generic:

```
public class MyListType<T> {

   public MyListType(string listName) {
      ListName = listName;
   }

   public string ListName {get; set;}

   public Func<List<T>, List<T>> Filter {get; private set;}

   public MyListType<T> WithFilter(Func<List<T>, List<T>> filter) {
      Filter = filter;
      return this;
   }
}
```

But if I understand your intent correct you probably would want something like this:

```
// In Project A
public class ListFilter(string name, Func<string, bool> filter) {
    public IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, string> nameSelector) 
           => list.Where(item => filter(nameSelector(item)));
}
// Used like
var filter = new ListFilter("Begins with 'A'", name => name.StartsWith("A"));
var people = new List<Person> {...}
var aPeople = beginsWithA.Filter(people, person => person.Name);
```

This lets you separate the part that does the filtering from the part that descides what to filter on.

An alternative would be to use a interface and generic restrictions to ensure your type actually has a name:

```
// in Project A
public interface INamedThing{
    string Name {get;}
}
public class ListFilter<T>(string name, Func<string, bool> filter) where T : INamedThing {
    public IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) 
           => list.Where(item => filter(item.Name));
}

// In Project B
public class Person : INamedThing { ... }

var filter = new ListFilter<Person>("Begins with 'A'", name => name.StartsWith("A"));
var people = new List<Person> {...}
var aPeople = beginsWithA.Filter(people);
```